# Python from different user accounts

Tags: python-3.x, pythonpath

I have an older user account that I still use (rarely), and it has Python installed. In my current user account, I also have Python installed. However, if I try to run Python from cmd here, there are some issues because it actually starts from the directory associated with my old user account. When I'm on this user account, how can I make Python run from the installation I have on this?

My OS is windows 10, and the `PATH` variable has the directory to the Python installation for my old user account as well as for my current one. But I think when I type Python into cmd, it starts from the old user directory.

`PATH`: `PATH=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Calibre2\;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\bin;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v901\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Users\Lewis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32;C:\Users\Lewis\.jupyter;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy3;C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy3\DLLs;C:\Users\L\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36;C:\Users\L\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\;C:\Users\L\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\;C:\Users\L\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Launcher\;C:\Users\L\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\L\Documents\Python Scripts\Learning;`

Comment: In order for other people to troubleshoot this, you need to add what OS you're using, the value of your `PATH` environment variable, and the locations of the Python executables.

Comment: And clarify what you mean by "the directory associated with my old user account". Is that the home directory or Python installation directory?

Comment: Updated the post. The reason I'm confused is that I pip installed a package and it is correctly installed in my latest user Python directory (L\...) but it does not exist in the older one. When I try to import, it doesn't find the module. I want to run Python from cmd from my current user installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove the old Python installation directories from your `PATH` for user `L`. Seems like it's just this one: `C:\Users\Lewis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32`.

I'm guessing you have both old and new directories in the system `PATH`, but since the directories are user-level, IMO they should be in each user's `PATH` instead. You can change the `PATH` variables in `sysdm.cpl` → "Advanced" → "Environment Variables".

Comment: For user `L` the old directory isn't there, the correct one is though. The two directories together are in the System variables. My User `L` path: `C:\Users\L\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\;C:\Users\L\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\;C:\Users\L\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Launcher\;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;`

Comment: @fffrost Ah, then you should remove the directories from the system PATH

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Although I guess that wasn't my problem because I'm still unable to import the module despite it being installed. To make things even more confusing, Python shell imports it, but when I run Python from cmd it doesn't find the package. The python shell says Python 3.6.5, while in cmd it says Python 3.6.6. I don't quite understand what's going on with that, it looks like it's installed in the same location..